# Параллелизм во Flutter и Dart - одновременное выполнение нескольких асинхронных запросов. Как правильно?

Tags: flutter, dart

Из АПИ хочу получить данные, но при этом в описании к АПИ сказано, что нужно получать данные одновременно сразу из нескольких таблиц и уже из запроса getStops, получить финальный результат.

То есть есть три списка

```
 List<RaceCard> list = [];
  List<Stop> stop = [];
  List<ScheduleVariants> sheduler = [];
```

и на каждый приходится по своему запросу к АПИ. Сейчас реализовываю это так, но в ответ получаю пустую страницу:

```
class Direction extends StatefulWidget {
  final int mvId;
  final int mrId;
  final int stId;
  const Direction({Key key, this.mrId, this.mvId, this.stId}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _DirectionState createState() => _DirectionState();
}

class _DirectionState extends State<Direction> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    _getData();
    super.initState();
  }

  List<RaceCard> list = [];
  List<Stop> stop = [];
  List<ScheduleVariants> sheduler = [];

  Future _getData() async {
   
    String basicAuth =
        'Basic ' + base64Encode(utf8.encode('$username:$password'));
    print(basicAuth);
  final results =   await Future.wait([
      http.get(
          Uri.parse(
              : basicAuth}),
      http.get(
          Uri.parse(
              ),
          headers: <String, String>{'authorization': basicAuth}),
    http.get(
        Uri.parse(
            "),
        headers: <String, String>{'authorization': basicAuth})
    ]);

  setState(() {
    list = json.decode(results[0].body);
    stop = json.decode(results[1].body);
    sheduler = json.decode(results[2].body);
    sheduler.where((element) => element.mrId == widget.mrId).toList();
    stop.where((element) => element.stId == widget.stId).toList();
    list.where((element) => element.stId == widget.stId).toList();
  });
  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: _getData(),
        builder: (context, projectSnap) {
    if (projectSnap.connectionState == ConnectionState.none &&
    projectSnap.hasData == null) {
      return Container();
    }
          return ListView.builder(itemCount: stop.length, itemBuilder: (context, index){
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(stop[index].stTitle),
            );
          });
        },),
    );
  }
}
```

В стэктрейсе такая ошибка:

```
E/flutter (18748): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected end of input (at character 1)
E/flutter (18748): 
E/flutter (18748): ^
E/flutter (18748): 
E/flutter (18748): #0      _ChunkedJsonParser.fail (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1404:5)
E/flutter (18748): #1      _ChunkedJsonParser.close (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:522:7)
E/flutter (18748): #2      _parseJson (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:41:10)
E/flutter (18748): #3      JsonDecoder.convert (dart:convert/json.dart:506:36)
E/flutter (18748): #4      JsonCodec.decode (dart:convert/json.dart:157:41)
E/flutter (18748): #5      _DirectionState._getData.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_app/main.dart:214:17)
E/flutter (18748): #6      State.setState (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1267:30)
E/flutter (18748): #7      _DirectionState._getData (package:flutter_app/main.dart:213:3)
E/flutter (18748): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (18748):
```

Comment: URL некорректные: вместо доменного имени имя документа; а в третьем случае еще и `/` пропущен. Ошибка у тебя на разборе данных: входная строка не являются валидным JSON (запросы к этой ошибке имеют посредственное отношение).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> одновременное выполнение нескольких асинхронных запросов. Как правильно?

"Правильно" - никак, потому что каких-то единых и однозначных правил не существует...
А относительно удобно - можно таким образом:

1. В классах моделей описываем фабричный конструктор `fromJson`, для разбора JSON-мапы *единичной* сущности в новый экземпляр объекта (или используем генерацию кода пакетом **json_serializable**)
2. Пишем какую-нибудь вспомогательную функцию запроса *списка* сущностей, для сокращения повторений кода
   Типа такой функции (код очень базовый и написан на ходу - не рекомендую его копипастить):

   ```
   Future<List<T>> fetchList<T>(String endpoint, {
     Map<String, String>? query,
     Map<String, String>? headers,
     required T Function(dynamic) itemFactory,
   }) async {
     final uri = Uri.https(apiHost, endpoint, query);
     final Map<String, String> mergedHeaders = (headers is Map)
       ? ({}..addAll(baseHeaders)..addAll(headers!))
       : baseHeaders;
     final response = await http.get(uri, headers: mergedHeaders);
     if (response.statusCode != 200)
       throw Exception('Error[${response.statusCode}] on GET ${uri.toString()}');
     return List<T>.from(jsonDecode(response.body).map<T>(itemFactory));
   }
   // предполагается что `apiHost` и `baseHeaders` объявлены в области видимости
   ```
3. Собственно, используем первые две вещи, и радуемся
   Например, в контексте этого вопроса, можно представить примерно такой код:

   ```
   try {
     // параллельные запросы с разбором полученных данных в List'ы
     final results = await Future.wait([
       fetchList<RaceCard>('getRaceCards.php',
         query: { 'fmt': 'json', 'mv_id': mv_id },
         itemFactory: (json) => RaceCard.fromJson(json),
       ),
       fetchList<Stop>('getStops.php',
         query: { 'fmt': 'json' },
         itemFactory: (json) => Stop.fromJson(json),
       ),
       fetchList<ScheduleVariants>('getMarshVariants.php',
         query: { 'fmt': 'json' },
         itemFactory: (json) => ScheduleVariants.fromJson(json),
       ),
     ], eagerError: true);
     // если выполнение дошло досюда, значит ошибок не возникло - пробуем изменить стейт
     setState(() {
       list      = results[0] as List<RaceCard>;
       stops     = results[1] as List<Stop>;
       shedulers = results[2] as List<ScheduleVariants>;
       /* .... */
     });
   } catch (err) {
     // тут какие-то действия при любой ошибке: выполнения одного из запросов, разбора данных в объект, изменения стейта, и т.д.
   }
   ```

В чем разница с кодом в вопросе:

- в том что код не придется дублировать в каждом классе стейта
  <sub>(т.к. классы модели сами отвечают за свое инстанцирование из JSON... а функцию запроса списка можно сделать методом суперкласса расширяющего либо `State`, либо базовый класс API-провайдера, и наследовать его по необходимости)</sub>
- в раннем отлове ошибок алгоритма, благодаря типизации полей модельных классов
  <sub>(к этому естественным образом обяжет код фабричного конструктора `fromJson`)</sub>
- в непадающем от каждого чиха приложении, и более удобной отладке.

---

Ну а ошибка `FormatException: Unexpected end of input (at character 1)` возникает при вызове `json.decode`: из-за попытки JSON-разбора строки которая не является валидным JSON (как я уже написал в комменте). Это проблема с данными, проблема содержимого ответа какого-то отдельного сервера в каком-то частном случае... к заданному общему вопросу, эта частная проблема по сути не относится (об адекватном/безопасном разборе конкретного серверного ответа можно задать отдельный вопрос, прикрепив к нему содержимое того что сервер присылает).

Принцип *общей* обработки ошибок (при любом из запросов) приведен в примере выше, в последнем блоке кода.
Такой подход используется когда принципиально не важно, какой из запросов повалится с ошибкой - чтобы, например, показать пользователю простое понятное уведомление не перегруженное "пугающими техническими подробностями".

Если же нужна индивидуальная обработка ошибок *каждого* из запросов в "пачке" - то это уже отдельная, и весьма обширная тема.
Такое можно сделать множеством разных способов: и через собственные классы исключений, и через коллбэки, и через переменную в состоянии, и через свой класс объекта запроса, и резолвом констант ошибок, и так далее...

Comment: а если я сливаю все запросы в один, то лучше использовать например Future<List<iterable>> или все же создать общий класс, куда записать все, что находится внутри тех, классов, которым соответствует запрос? Сейчас у меня разбит каждый  запрос на одну модель: то есть 4 запроса - 4 модели. В конечном счете я хочу направить в UI один единственный список, который будет прогнан через ListView.builder, который выдаст мне уже отфильтрованные элементы последнего запроса getStop. В BoringFlutterDevelopmentShow  видел подобное, но там все строилось вокруг одного запроса, а не 4ех

Comment: @inkwelll075, делай столько моделей, сколько у тебя есть сущностей. Делить на классы желательно не по коду, а по смыслу. Один запрос может возвращать и несколько моделей, значит разбирать в несколько объектов с разными классами. Например: если считали профиль пользователя, содержащий информацию о нем, список его заказов, и список обращений в поддержку - то создаем экземпляр User, кучку экземпляров Order, и кучку экземпляров Ticket, а не один экземпляр UserWithOrdersAndTickets. Вообще редко бэкэнд так соединяет данные (плохая практика), но это вымышленный пример, и надеюсь что его логика ясна.

Comment: спасибо, да, у меня логически поделено, что несколько экземпляров класса, а не в один все свалено. Спасибо за инфу, буду работать дальше над этим.

Comment: @inkwelll075, модели в вопросе я считаю корректными, рекомендую только более грамотно разделить ответственности: чтобы класс модели сам отвечал за свою (де)сериализацию, инкапсулируя эту логику. Также, советую описать классы списков, т.е. вместо `List<*>` завести несколько классов `*List` поместив в них методы сериализации (делегируя разбор): просто чтобы не повторять код каждый раз (но это уже дело вкуса, и совсем необязательно делать именно так - в ответе вот предложен альтернативный вариант: вспомогательная дженерик функция для разбора в список чегоугодно. Такой вариант тоже вполне удобен).